# How to write basic script to search a log for 2 words and place line in a new document

Tags: search, logging, automation, document

I am working with some random logs at work on a Windows computer. I am just learning bash script and cant figure this out. The lines I am lookin for contain error and launcher, and I would like the line on the log that contains both of those words to then be copied to a text document that I can reference later. If you all could help me out and maybe walk through what you are doing step by step. I am working hard to try and figure this out all to no avail.

-Cant figure out how to grep for a word and then another

-I then cant figure out how to copy the line to a new document so I can reference later

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep 'disk.*error|error.*disk' doc.txt > output.txt
```

This line of code should do what you are looking for, It will find all lines in `doc.txt` that have the word disk and error on the same line and save the results in `output.txt`.